# Overlay button over all images

Tags: javascript, html

Basically i want to loop through the html and get all the pictures and overlay a small button on them on hover, so when the user is clicking on that button, a bunch of info about that picture will appear. Right now i can overlay a small icon over a photo that will generate a popup when it's clicked, but i don't know how to dynamically add a icon on all photos on hover. This is what i've done so far http://jsfiddle.net/s5sp1h6e/1/

```
//Getting all the images
function getAllImages() 
{
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
    var srcList = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) 
    {
        srcList.push(images[i].src);
    }
}

I've found a script that overlays a image over all images but every time i'm changing the size of the image i'm overlaying, the script stops working and i can't understand why.
```

If i want to change in this line the width and the height to be given hardcoded, the script stops working.

```
var overlay = $('<img class="protectionOverlay" src="' + overlayImg + '" width="' +       img.width() + '" height="' + img.height() + '"/>') bla bla..


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(function() 
{
    var overlayImg = 'http://www.privdog.com/PrivDog/logo-medium.png';
    var useOnAllImages = true;
    // Preload the pixel
    var preload = new Image();
    preload.src = overlayImg;
    $('img').on('mouseenter touchstart', function(e) 
    {
        // Only execute if this is not an overlay or skipped
        var img = $(this);
        if (img.hasClass('protectionOverlay')) return;
        if (!useOnAllImages && !img.hasClass('protectMe')) return; // The script will be applied to all images. IF u don't want this -> useOnAllImages = false and class="protectMe"
        // Get the real image's position, add an overlay
        var pos = img.offset(); 
        //var xx = overlayImg.offset();
        //alert(xx.top);
        var overlay = $('<img class="protectionOverlay" src="' + overlayImg + '" width="' + img.width() + '" height="' + img.height() + '"/>').css({position: 'absolute', zIndex: 9999999, left: pos.left, top: pos.top}).appendTo('body').bind('mouseleave', function() 
        {
            setTimeout(function(){ overlay.remove(); }, 0, $(this));
        });
        if ('ontouchstart' in window) $(document).one('touchend', function(){ setTimeout(function(){ overlay.remove(); }, 0, overlay); });
    });

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current implementation

Comment: Well it works for one picture, but i don't know how to add this behavior dynamically for all the images. Imagine i loop through the html, insert all the img tags into an array and i don't know how to add a overlay button for all the images. I don't know if i am very clear..

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add a an event handler for mouseover and mouseout. In the handler apply the necessary changes to the image.

```
$("img").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(this).addClass("overlay-class");
    var icon = $("<span class='icon' />").appendTo(document.body);
    // logic to position the icon
}).on("mouseout", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("overlay-class");
    $(".icon").remove();
});
```

Comment: I've tried to implement what you said Konstantin but i think i'm missing something. I've imagined a html with 3 pictures and i m trying to add a icon on each and every one on hover but i'm not doing something right. This is what i've done http://jsfiddle.net/3b370vkt/

Comment: Done it if someone encounters this problem. first method http://jsfiddle.net/3b370vkt/3/    2nd method http://jsfiddle.net/s5sp1h6e/2/ .Thank you monkeyinsight and monners.